# How to run Sinatra App in Passenger with Nginx?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

I'm trying to run a very simple Sinatra app using my existing Nginx & Passenger setup. I'm familiar with running Rails on Passenger but this is my first time setting up Sinatra.

I've installed Sinatra through bundler and RVM. Take a look at my configuration and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  demo.my-example.com;
  root /home/user/demo.my-example.com/sinatra;     

  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1@my_gemset/ruby;
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

/home/user/demo.my-example.com/sinatra/config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
disable :run, :reload
set :environment, :production

require "./stripe"
run StripeApp
```

/home/user/demo.my-example.com/sinatra/stripe.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class StripeApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do 
   "Hello world"
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: The Nginx error log shows: [error] 21037#0: *7 directory index of "/home/user/demo.my-example.com/sinatra/" is forbidden, server: demo.my-example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.my-example.com"

Comment: Shouldn’t the `root` entry point at your apps `public` dir, not the apps top level dir?

Comment: Thanks @matt I had assumed I didn't need a public folder for Sinatra but when I created one things fell into place. I had to remove disable :run, :reload and set :environment, :production from the config.ru also.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? Please send Right answer for it. @MarkRobinson

Comment: @harsh4u see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/home/user/demo.my-example.com/sinatra/config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths

require "./stripe"
run StripeApp
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. Is it for CentOS? I have a issue on centOS. Is there any specific configuration for it?

Comment: @harsh4u it's the same configuration in development as production